# Transform Amazon Fire TV into Nintendo Gaming Console

Tags: rooting, emulators

I'm wondering if I could install N64 and Gamecube Emulators on an Amazon Fire TV. Will I have to root the device? Is it possible without?

Will PS3 Controllers work wireless and is there something I have to have in mind for buying No-Name Bluetooth Controllers?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Just google for bluetooth controllers that FTV supports. I have a Nyko and Ouya controller that I use on mine. You don't need to root in order to play emulators. You just need to side load the apk files. Not all emulators will work and some will work better than others. You will however be limited to the space on your unrooted FTV though. Having a rooted FTV will let you play games from a flash thumb drive or HDD.